# Pandas Dataframe and Series join returns empty Dataframe or NaN column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, series

The issue that I am having is that when I try to join a Dataframe and a Series, for some reason the resulting Dataframe is either empty or has a column of NaN values. I am trying to figure out why this is happening.

The Series looks like this:

```
index
110     0.135135
111     0.000000
1110    0.000000
```

The Dataframe looks like this:

```
           mean         std
index                        
1101     -41.000000   46.305225
1102     -58.724998  126.810371
1110      -6.375000   12.915982
```

When I don't specify 'how', I get this:

```
          mean        std             series_col
index                                 
1101     -41.000000   46.305225       NaN
1102     -58.724998   126.810371      NaN
1110      -6.375000   12.915982       NaN
```

This is how I tried to join the two using how:

```
merged = df1.join(series1, how='inner')
```

I get this output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [mean, std, series_col]
Index: []
```

I can't figure out what's wrong. I think it must be an index issue, but I know for certain that both the Dataframe and Series have some intersecting indices on which to match the data.

Let me know if there's any other useful information I can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem indexes are not same `dtypes`, so get `NaN`.

Solution is cast both indexes to `int` or both to `str` for align:

```
series1.index = series1.index.astype(int)
df1.index = df1.index.astype(int)
```

---

```
series1.index = series1.index.astype(str)
df1.index = df1.index.astype(str)
```

For me it return:

```
#inner join
merged = df1.join(series1, how='inner')
print (merged)
        mean        std  val
index                       
1110  -6.375  12.915982  0.0
```

---

```
#default left join
merged = df1.join(series1)
#same as:  
merged = df1.join(series1, how='left')
print (merged)
            mean         std  val
index                            
1101  -41.000000   46.305225  NaN
1102  -58.724998  126.810371  NaN
1110   -6.375000   12.915982  0.0
```

---

```
merged = df1.join(series1, how='outer')
print (merged)
            mean         std       val
index                                 
110          NaN         NaN  0.135135
1101  -41.000000   46.305225       NaN
1102  -58.724998  126.810371       NaN
111          NaN         NaN  0.000000
1110   -6.375000   12.915982  0.000000
```

---

```
merged = df1.join(series1, how='right')
print (merged)
        mean        std       val
index                            
110      NaN        NaN  0.135135
111      NaN        NaN  0.000000
1110  -6.375  12.915982  0.000000
```

Comment: I thought joining with how='inner' would just look for the indices that intersect and pull out those rows? If that's not true, how do I match them on indices?

Comment: Yes, exactly, it return `intersect` indices only.

Comment: but problem is there are ints and strings, see solution - cast both to int or both to str.

Answer (score 3):

When I did this I got

```
df1.join(series1)

           mean         std    1
1101 -41.000000   46.305225  NaN
1102 -58.724998  126.810371  NaN
1110  -6.375000   12.915982  0.0
```

I'm guessing one of your indices are strings and the other are ints

Comment: Actually, you're right. For the Series, I needed to create the index from two columns, each containing half the id value. I needed them to be one after the other, not to add them together, and I couldn't think of any way to do it other than by making them strings. Do you have a suggestion for how I could fix this?